# App subversion to float

Tags: ios, floating-point, version, cgfloat

I am getting my app's version like this:

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

And then trying to convert it to a float like this:

```
[version floatValue]
```

Now that all works great, but when I have a minor version like "1.1.1" everything behind the second decimal point is truncated.

What is the best way to keep everything behind the second decimal point?

Comment: How do you expect it to be converted? In real numbers, you only have one decimal point...

Comment: Since 1.1.1 isn't a valid float, what is your goal here?

Comment: Probably better to map to an int -- "1.1.1" => 0x01010100 or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it in sync with how you started...

```
int major, minor, bug;
NSArray *versionItems = [version componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
major = [[versionItems objectAtIndex:0] intValue]; 
minor = [[versionItems objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
bug = [[versionItems objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
```

But I'd recommend looking at this..

[How do I determine the OS version at runtime in OS X or iOS (without using Gestalt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072804/mac-os-x-10-8-replacement-for-gestalt-for-testing-os-version-at-runtime)

Comment: don't forget to cast those NSString's into NSNumbers or integers