# python finding mac os build number

Tags: python, macos

How can I find my Mac OS X build number? And if possible, is there a way to find it using Python? I would like to use Python so that I can automatically make OS X .app files in an automated fashion.

EDIT: I see the 'Marked as duplicate' messages, and realize that people think that I mean the Mac OS X VERSION number. I'm talking about the BUILD number.

Comment: What do you mean by "build number"?

Comment: The bit of information needed in the Info.plist file to create applications called BuildMachineOSBuild, the build number being shown [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1633)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough, the OS X build number does not seem to be available through the `platform` module. OS X does provide a `sw_vers` command which can be used to retrieve the build number through `os.popen`.

**Example:**

```
import os
print(os.popen("sw_vers -buildVersion").read().strip())
```

**Output on OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks:**

```
13E28
```

Not ideal, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `platform` module? It will get you just about everything Python knows about the version of the OS, as well as info about the Python interpreter itself.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.htm

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697362/871119

A Python version might look like:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.dylib")
size = ctypes.c_uint(256)
buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size.value)

if libc.sysctlbyname("kern.osversion", buf, ctypes.byref(size), None, 0) == 0:
    print buf.value
else:
    print "Fails"
```

Works on the system provided version of Python on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

To find the current working platform, I would usually use the

```
    sys
```

module, with a .platform to get this code

```
    import sys
    sys.platform
'win32'
```