# How to check the OS X version from R?

Tags: r, macos

You can check whether you are running OS X using `Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Darwin"`.

On Windows, finer control is possible by checking for specific versions of the OS using `utils::win.version()`.

*How do you check the version of OS X?*  (I can't find a `mac.version` or `osx.version` function.  There are some [low-level OS commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11072804/134830) for finding the version, but I'm not aware of any R wrapper.)

Do `Sys.info()["release"]` or `system("uname --kernel-release", intern = TRUE)` return anything useful? (I don't have a machine to check.)

Comment: I am not on OS X, but doesn't `R.version$os` provide useful information? ([source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Version.html))

Comment: I only know about Linux and Windows. There, `R.version$system` gives information on the OS in general and `sessionInfo()$running` provides details concerning the version of the OS that is used.

Comment: doesnt `Sys.info()` already tells you the version name in `version` field. In windows the value in the field `version` and the output of `win.version` is same. it has also clubbed sysname and release name in the output that is it.

Comment: @Pascal The help page for `R.version` explicitly states "Do not use R.version$os to test the platform the code is running on".

Comment: @RichieCotton It also says "## a good way to detect OS X:
if(grepl("^darwin", R.version$os)) message("running on OS X")"

Comment: `.Platform` reports the Os type, but not the version number.

Comment: @DhawalKapil `Sys.info()["release"]` looks promising.  I don't have access to a mac, so if you can post some examples of what it returns under OS X, that's worth at least an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you actually want, I would use:

```
system("uname -r")
14.5.0
```

or

```
system("uname -s")
Darwin
```

or

```
system("uname -v")
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sys.info()["sysname"]` returns "Darwin" on Mac OS X.

`Sys.info()["release"]` tells you what version of Mac OS X. For example, "13.4.0" is Mac OS X 10.9.5.

There probably is no need to do a `system()` call: `Sys.info()["version"]` seems to return exactly the same as `system("uname -v")`. And this version really combines different pieces of information and is not convenient for just checking whether or not you're running on Mac. For example

```
> Sys.info()["version"]
version
"Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 16 09:03:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64"
```

Comment: FYI, under windows only `Sys.info()["release"]` gives a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Sys.info()` to get most of the information about the current platform:

**Example**:

```
osname_version<-c(paste(" System: ",Sys.info()[['sysname']],
                      "\nVersion: ",Sys.info()[['version']],
                      "\nRelease: ",Sys.info()[['release']],
                      "\nMachine: ",Sys.info()[['machine']]))
cat(osname_version,"\n")
```

**Result**:

```
 System:  Linux 
Version:  #1 SMP Fri Sep 2 15:45:09 CEST 2011 
Release:  2.6.32.46 
Machine:  i686
```

More Information: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.info.html

Answer (score 0):

Since `Sys.info()` gives the kernel version rather than the product version, I've opted for using [`sw_vers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sw_vers.1.html) instead.

```
as.numeric_version(system("sw_vers -productVersion", intern = TRUE))
```

Comment: Nicer wrappers to this now in the devel version of `assertive.reflection`. https://bitbucket.org/richierocks/assertive.reflection