# systemVersion equivalent for AppKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, appkit, uidevice

Is there a way to get systemName (e.g. macOS or Mac OS X) in AppKit?

Essentially, I am looking for a AppKit equivalent of the following UIKit command:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]
```

**EDIT:**
Please note that I am not looking for OS version, I am looking for name of the OS. For example on systemName on iOS returns "ios"

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *systemName;        // e.g. @"iOS"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24004701/2594699

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the OS version at runtime in OS X or iOS (without using Gestalt)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072804/how-do-i-determine-the-os-version-at-runtime-in-os-x-or-ios-without-using-gesta)

Comment: How many different operating systems do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [NSProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsprocessinfo).

For example, one of the handy method is (which is localized):

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString]
```

And another one which always returns `NSMACHOperatingSystem` on macOS but is already deprecated:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemName]
```

Comment: Sorry I pasted the incorrect command in my question above earlier. I have modified it to the correct one. I am looking for system name, not version.

Comment: Updated the answer but also wondering if you already know it's AppKit, which system names are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting "macOS" in case of Sierra and "Mac OS X" in case of previous versions. Very similar to what systemName does on iOS.

Comment: In that case I'd say it's probably more easier to just get version number and do a simple mapping.

Comment: I do understand that creating a mapping is a possible solution, I was just trying to see if there is an existing method.