# Cocoa compatible with different Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa app which has different features in Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8 (The deployment target is 10.7). For example, in 10.8 I have a button for `Sharing Service` while in 10.7 the button is hidden.

The problem here is how can I know which kind of Mac OS is there while my app is running. For iOS, I can get it from `UIDevice`. But for Cocoa, I don't find the similar class.

Currently, I detect the OS using:

```
- (BOO)isServiceAvalable
{
   if (NSClassFromString(@"A_Unique_Class_In_One_OS"))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I hope there is more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Kindly check these SO questions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885911/how-to-get-the-mac-os-x-system-version

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically

Comment: If you wish to do backward compatibility then...
Set the Base SDK to Current version of Mac (ex. 10.7)
Set the Deployment SDK to older version (ex.1.4)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya，Gestalt is deprecated in Mac OS 10.8.

Comment: few others will be there, i simply googled and found many links, i copied only 2 of them :)

Answer (score 0):

- **StackOverflow:** [os version checking in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115373/os-version-checking-in-cocoa)
- **StackOverflow:** [How to get the Mac OS X system version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885911/how-to-get-the-mac-os-x-system-version)
- **StackOverflow:** [How can I determine the running Mac OS X version programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically)
- **Cocoa Dev Central:** [Checking the User's Mac OS X Version](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000067.php)

Answer (score 0):

If Gestalt is deprecated as scorpiozj mentions then here's a simple NSApplescript way to do it...

```
NSString* getSystemVersion() {
    NSString* returnString = nil;
    NSString* cmd = @"return system version of (get system info)";
    NSAppleScript* theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:cmd];
    NSDictionary* errorDict = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* result = [theScript executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
    [theScript release];
    if (errorDict) {
        returnString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error:%@ %@", [errorDict valueForKey:@"NSAppleScriptErrorNumber"], [errorDict valueForKey:@"NSAppleScriptErrorMessage"]];
    } else {
        returnString = [result stringValue];
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Is NSAppleScript available in the sandbox cocoa app?

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe you should be OK with this because you are not controlling another application, you are only accessing a value from system events.